# 2 Consecutive JQuery Posts, second executed first

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, response

Please help me with this...

I have  to pass values to a php file for save, but if a check box has been selected, it has to execute the second jquery post using the return value from the first. But it seems like the second jquery post is being executed first, here's my code:

```
if($action=="save_prod")
    {   
        var remember = document.getElementById('chk');
        var $suppid=document.getElementById('supp').value;
        var $categlist=document.getElementById('categlist').value;
        var $prodname=document.getElementById('prodname').value;
        var $proddesc=document.getElementById('proddesc').value;

        $.post(baseurl+'index.php/main/newproduct',{"categlist" : $categlist,"prodname" : $prodname," proddesc" : $proddesc,"supp" : $suppid},function(response) 
        {
        $lastid=response;
                if($lastid != 0)
                {
                    alert("Product has been saved with ID=" + $lastid);
                    document.getElementById('resp').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
                    window.location.href=baseurl +"index.php/main/mgtprods/?key="+ $suppid;
                }
            });

        if (remember.checked)
         {
            //alert($lastid);
            $.post(baseurl+'index.php/main/newitem',{"prodlist" : $lastid ,"itlist" : 0,"itcost" : 0, "supp" : $suppid, "itname" : $prodname, "itunit" : "pc" },function(response) 
            {
                document.getElementById('resp').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
                //window.location.href=baseurl +"index.php/main/mgtprods/?key="+ $suppid;
            });

         }  
    }
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You're making asynchronous calls, you can't predict which one is first. You may use the deferred object to set up a queue of promises. Check http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: or put the second post in the callback of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ajax functions (`$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, `$.post()` ... ) all return a [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object which wraps the underlying `jqXHR` object.

Take advantage of the [`Deferred.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) function to chain two asynchronous calls :

```
//your first $.post :
$.post(...)
.then(function(){
    if (remember.checked) {
        //your second $.post :
        $.post(...);
    } 
});
```

Using it this way, the second function will be called only if the first call is succesful (nothing will be triggered if the first call results in an error).

---

Your first callback contains a redirect : `window.location.href=baseurl +"index.php/main/mgtprods/?key="+ $suppid;`. You will have to choose more precisely when you want to execute this redirection.

Here is a way to trigger the redirection after the second call if `remember` is checked, or right after the first call if `remember` isn't checked, by chaining `Deferred` objects :

```
$.post(... /* remove the redirection from the first callback */)
.then(function(){
    if (remember.checked) {
        //your second $.post : return the Deferred corresponding to this call
        return $.post(... /* remove the redirection from the second callback */);
    } else {
        // else, return the first Deferred object :
        return this;
    }
}).then(function(){
    /* do your redirection here : */
    window.location.href=baseurl +"index.php/main/mgtprods/?key="+ $suppid;
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Semt/)

Comment: This does not execute the second post

Comment: Indeed : your first callback redirects to a new page : `window.location.href = baseurl +"index.php/main/mgtprods/?key="+ $suppid`, which will stop js execution and load new page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if($action=="save_prod") {   
    var remember = document.getElementById('chk');
    var $suppid=document.getElementById('supp').value;
    var $categlist=document.getElementById('categlist').value;
    var $prodname=document.getElementById('prodname').value;
    var $proddesc=document.getElementById('proddesc').value;

    $.post(baseurl+'index.php/main/newproduct',{"categlist" : $categlist,"prodname" : $prodname," proddesc" : $proddesc,"supp" : $suppid},function(response) {
        $lastid=response;
        if (remember.checked) {
            //alert($lastid);
            $.post(baseurl+'index.php/main/newitem',{"prodlist" : $lastid ,"itlist" : 0,"itcost" : 0, "supp" : $suppid, "itname" : $prodname, "itunit" : "pc" },function(response) {
                document.getElementById('resp').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
                //window.location.href=baseurl +"index.php/main/mgtprods/?key="+ $suppid;
            });
        }  
        if($lastid != 0) {
            alert("Product has been saved with ID=" + $lastid);
            document.getElementById('resp').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
            window.location.href=baseurl +"index.php/main/mgtprods/?key="+ $suppid;
        }
    });
}
```

All I've done is move the 2nd post into the callback function of the first.  You could alternatively add a `.done()` method to the first post and add the 2nd one to that, but it has the same effect.

Comment: This doesn't seem to call the second post ... do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I've moved the 2nd post to before `window.location.href` so it should work fine now.